# Android Venmo API leads to webview that does not allows a user to pay

Tags: android, venmo

So I copied this piece of code from Venmo API in our Android App (https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-android).

```
 try {
    Intent venmoIntent = VenmoLibrary.openVenmoPayment("2019", "EasySplit","xxxx(some valid user name)", "0.1", "Testing", "pay");
    startActivityForResult(venmoIntent, 1); //1 is the requestCode we are using for Venmo. Feel free to change this to another number. 
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) //Venmo native app not install on device, so let's instead open a mobile web version of Venmo in a WebView
{
    Intent venmoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VenmoWebViewActivity.class);
    String venmo_uri = VenmoLibrary.openVenmoPaymentInWebView("2019", "EasySplit","xxx(some valid user name)", "0.1", "Testing", "pay");
    venmoIntent.putExtra("url", venmo_uri);
    startActivityForResult(venmoIntent, 1);
}
```

However, the problem is that after I go to the webview and log in, I simply cannot pay. I would expect a button I could click just to pay but there is no such a button there. I could see the text "Pay (recipent name) (some amount)" but it seems I cannot buy.
Any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?
Any help is highly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: I work at Braintree, same company as Venmo. We're looking into the problem now.

Comment: This is being tracked at https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-android/pull/3

Comment: Now being tracked at https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-android/pull/4

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the next release.